# how to keep a reference for the requests in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping a page from links created out from numbers,

```
www.some_page.com/some_number
```

when the pages exist the url changes, when I try:

```
response.request.url
```

I don't get the:

```
www.some_page.com/some_number
```

That I'm using to make the search, so I lost the number I'm using to get the page, I need to keep this number to match the data again.

How can I pass some value, the number in this as an argument when I make the request and get it back in the response?

Comment: I made this question but wasn't detailed enough, it was necessary to make other question once I was more clear about what did i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what [`.meta`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) is for:

```
def parse(self, response):
     return scrapy.Request(url, 
                           meta={"number": number},
                           callback=self.parse_page)

def parse_page(self, response):
    print(response.meta["number"])
```